# Display All attributes in layer if attributes have zero product in magento

Tags: php, magento

My Code is here,

But i want to display all product have product and have not product .

so please help me

Thanks
Er Amit Anand

Comment: <?php

 foreach($_filters as $_filter){ ?>
<?php if($_filter->getItemsCount()){ ?>
<div class="list-group left-cat">
       <h2><?php echo $this->__($_filter->getName()) ?></h2>
       <span class="list-group-item"><?php echo $_filter->getHtml() ?></span>
 </div>
 <?php } ?>
 <?php } ?>

Comment: any one suggest me ,how to display all attributes with have product and have not product in magento layer

Comment: Do any idea about this problem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is not possible in the search layered nav.
But for categories, it's possible.
You just have to edit each attribute and set the field `Used in layered navigation` to `Filtrable (no results)`.

Comment: Plz explain how to passible in category

Comment: Marius Thankyou soch much , i have got the solution and all attributes are showing ..

Comment: Thanks for help me . i have solved this problem .again thanks a lot